# Filter Json file with strange format

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to filter the number of access per city of my website, But the answer I get from the API is kinda strange and diferent from other jsons files that i have worked with.

I want to filter the Dimension AKA city like "Sao Paulo" and "Rio de Janeiro", also the number of visitors linked to the class, named as values such as "555" and 238"

So the json file looks like this:

```
[{"columnHeader":{"dimensions":["ga:city"],"metricHeader":{"metricHeaderEntries":[{"name":"ga:users","type":"INTEGER"}]}},"data":{"rows":[{"dimensions":["(not set)"],"metrics":[{"values":["984"]}]},
{"dimensions":["Sao Paulo"],"metrics":[{"values":["555"]}]},
{"dimensions":["Belo Horizonte"],
...
{"dimensions":["Xanxere"],"metrics":[{"values":["1"]}]}],"totals":[{"values":["5626"]}],"rowCount":544,"minimums":[{"values":["1"]}],"maximums":[{"values":["984"]}]}}]
```

(Link to the full json file: https://pastebin.com/mM6XxeRq)

I tried to extract the values using simple for loop while searching for the item named "dimensions".

```
import json

with open("test.json") as f:
    for line in f:
        names = (x['dimensions'] for x in json.loads(line))
        for name in names:
            print(name)
```

But I get this error:

```
KeyError: 'dimensions'
```

any clue on what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: That's not valid json. It looks like [jsonl](https://jsonlines.org/). Also what is `item`? You haven't posted the relevant portions of your code.

Comment: pretty strange, because any json viewer is able to read it, why json's library for python wouldn't be?

Comment: @gustavomatteo which jsonviewer is able to read it? I tested it in https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer. It says `Parse error on line 1:`.

Comment: maybe its the way i typed the text here,. I'll put the full json at this pastebin https://pastebin.com/mM6XxeRq

Comment: Can you paste your full code in the question?

Comment: I'll change the code for the one bellow here in the answers since the error stills the same even with that code

Comment: Your question is misleading. The JSON you've posted here starts with a `{` while the one in the pastebin starts with a `[`. You are also missing the commas between dictionaries/objects.

Comment: Noted, just changed the JSON

Comment: Your code is assuming that each top-level element in your JSON record has a `['dimensions']` dictionary entry. I'm not going to analyse your long input in depth, but the dimensions keys I found were deeper in the structure. `KeyError` means you're trying to access a key in a dict where that key does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        names = (x['name'] for x in json.loads(line))
        for name in names:
            print(name)
```

Comment: Nop, still the same error while searching for the item ```keyError```

Comment: i think you faced "filenotfounderror" error , you need add your file name...

Comment: not the case, I changed the Question to fit it better